# Mongod access denied

Tags: mongodb

I'm beginner in MongoDB.I tried to install Mongodb 4.0.2 version.I'm using windows 10 OS.It typed mongod.It shows 
**This App can't run on your PC**
[image]
.
**Access denied**.
[image]
After I typed Mongo. It's shows:
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
[image]

and I tried to create one collection it's working and tried to find the collection.

[image]
but **how can I solve the mongod app can't run on your pc**

can anyone solve this problem? Thanks in advance.....

Comment: check this solution https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power/this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc/d4869176-98fa-45b7-baf9-23c083335148?auth=1

Comment: I have tried but no use...It's not working Do you have any other solution....